# connecting to multiple peers over wi-fi

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I have to implement wifi connection with more than one device at a time. In the current example, if i am connecting any two peers, data can be exchanged between them but those devices are no more available in other devices. 
      I want to implement something like server-client over wifi. In which server can communicate with all and client can communicate with server. All simultaneously. 
It is something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914382/connecting-to-multiple-peers-on-the-iphone)

I want to know is it possible to connect with more than 1 device simultaneously over wifi? If yes, then what is the maximum number of devices that can be connected in same pattern?

Comment: Are you synchronizing data in the background or does it have to communicate with each device real time?  that may change your approach.  for example, if it's just syncing, your bg thread could iterate over devices exchanging data where real time interactive exchange (like a game) might require more optimal multiple connections.

Comment: It needs to communicate with each device real time as well.

Comment: If i am not allowing them to communicate but to send data to each device 1 ater another. Is it possible to send to all the devices one after one by connecting to devices one after another programmatically?

Comment: @Hina, unfortunately both the questions haven't been answered! This happens when either question fail to grab attention (97 views only) or the attention of right people! You may need to sacrifice your bounty! (min 50) to get possible answers..